# Tikz - three pictures in two pages in landscape mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, landscape, includegraphics

I would like to have three pictures on two pages (A4 in landscape mode) with `tikz` in the following manner:

**Middle picture:**

- The picture in the middle is halved (at 50 %) into two parts, one part 
  shall be added to the right side of the first page and on the left side of the second page.
- Both parts of middle picture shall be right at the border of the page (right on the first page/left in the second).

**Outer pictures:**

- The other two pictures shall be on the left side (first page) and right side (second page), respectively.
- Both shall have the same distance (i. e. 2 cm) to the picture in the middle.
- Both pictures shall be right at the border of their corresponding page, left on the first page and right on the second.

**All pictures:**

- All picture shall have the height of the paper.

The issue I have with my current code is that I have to adjust the pictures by myself. However, I would like `tikz` and LaTeX do everything for me "automatically". How can I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm, landscape, a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale}

\begin{document}

\par\noindent
\hspace{-.1cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \vspace{21cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\paperheight, trim={18cm 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image}
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{minipage}\hfill
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \vspace{21cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{minipage}

\par\noindent
\hspace{-13.8cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \vspace{21cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}
    \end{tikzpicture}     
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \vspace{21cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=\paperheight, trim={18cm 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image} % l b r t
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm, landscape, a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{2*\paperwidth/3-1cm} % kept local
\node at ([xshift=-\paperwidth/6-1cm]current page.center){%
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
\node at (current page.east){%
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
~
\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{2*\paperwidth/3-1cm} % kept local
\node at ([xshift=\paperwidth/6+1cm]current page.center){%
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\paperheight]{example-image-c}};
\node at (current page.west){%
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Added the gap. (Note that computing `\mywidth` twice is not a blunder.)

Comment: Hi marmot, thank you for your solution. Yes, almost. Can you please add a space of 2cm between picture A and the left part of B and between picture C and the right part of B?

Comment: @TilHund Sure. Sorry, I just overread it.

Comment: Awesome, marmot, this solution is perfect. What does the `~` do in the code?

Comment: @TilHund Nothing except for putting something invisible such that `\clearpage` generates a new page.

Comment: Hi, marmot, last thing: How can I label, i. e. `(image)` the node with picture A?

Comment: @TilHund Sorry, I do not understand the request. Could you please rephrase it? Do you want to put a label somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: Usually, one can label nodes in tikz, like `node[label=image]` or `\node (image) at (0,0) {a};` for positing, right? How can I label the above node `\node at ([xshift=-\paperwidth/6-1cm]current page.center){%
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};` correctly?

Comment: @TilHund Labels are also just nodes. If you use them in the way you propose, the labels will end up outside the picture. You could do `\node[label={[anchor=south,yshift=2em]below:pic A}] at ([xshift=-\paperwidth/6-1cm]current page.center){%
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};` or just `\node (picA) at ([xshift=-\paperwidth/6-1cm]current page.center){%
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
\node[anchor=south] at (picA|-current page.south) {pic A};`.